# If a circle can be inscribed in two quadrilaterals, then circle can be inscribed also in the quadrilateral $ABCD$

Tags: geometry

> Show that if a circle can be inscribed in quadrilateral $1$ ($AESH$) and in quadrilateral $2$ ($KCLS$), then circle can be inscribed also in the quadrilateral $ABCD$.

Here is a picture:

[image]

The places where inscribed circle is tangent to quadrilateral $1$ are marked as red points (blue points for places where inscribed circle is tangent to quadrilateral $2$).

As you see I've already took into account same lengths of some sides somming form the fact of inscribed circles (lengths: $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h$). Then I think that I need to use the fact that both circles are also inscribed in bigger tiangles:

- circle that is inscribed in quadrilateral $1$ is also inscribed in triangles $AEG$ and $AFH$
- circle that is inscribed in quadrilateral $2$ is also inscribed in triangles $SKG$ and $SFL$

From that I got $4$ equations:

- $n+g = m + h$
- $m+h + e + c = o + p + d$
- $l+g = k + f$
- $k + f + e + c = b + i + j$

But I don't know what to do next. Ultimately I need to prove that: $AB + DC = AD + BC$.

Comment: Could you tell the origin of this *nice* problem ?

Comment: My younger brother got it form a set of exercises from 2018, preparing high school students for a geometry test. I tried to help him but can't figure it out.

Comment: I have attempted to solve this problem but, like many of these "sangaku-type questions" the solution can be tricky. Drawing an *exact* figure would be a first step in order to see maybe a hidden property...

Comment: This is problem 2.63 in "[Mathematical Olympiad Treasures](https://artofmaths.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/mathematical-olympiad-treasures-2ed-springer-2011.pdf)" by Titu Andreescu and Bogdan Enescu. Its solution is based on problem 2.62 from the same book.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll have a look.